# Is this a TTL AND gate?

Tags: digital-logic, ttl, logic-gates

If not, can somebody explain it? Or suggest an easy way to understand it?

[image: Link]

Comment: https://courseware.ee.calpoly.edu/~dbraun/courses/ee307/S06/Other/02_17.html

Comment: Your diagram is actually a NAND gate. JIm Dearden's link discusses the design of an AND gate. Compare and contrast.

Comment: What is the use of T5 here?

Comment: T5 and T4 form a Darlington pair as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned the circuit you linked to is a 3-input NAND gate (7410), not an AND.

This is a pretty standard circuit for a TTL logic gate, except that instead of the diode between the two totem-pole output transistors shown in Keith's answer for most 74xx gates, your circuit uses a [Darlington pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) (T4 and T5) to do the same function as the diode: raise the effective V\$_{BE}\$ of the logic-high transistor.

(One other difference is the addition of reverse diodes from the inputs to ground; this has nothing to do with functionality but are there to handle negative spikes.)

All that is necessary to turn a NAND into an AND is to add an inverter to the circuit.  On a circuit board, this could literally be done by adding a separate inverter like a 7404 after the NAND gate.  To add the inverter your existing NAND circuit however, it's not convenient to add it to the output since we'd have to replicate the totem pole output again.  So instead, it can be inserted right after the input transistor T1 like so (new circuitry in red):

[image]

So this turns the 7410 into a 7411 (3-input AND gate).

**Here's how it works.**  If all inputs to the input transistor T1 are high (logic 1), transistor T1 will be off.  The new inverter transistor T6 will then be on, and T2 will be off (instead of on in the NAND configuration).  T3's base voltage will be held close to 0, so T3 will be turned off.  Meanwhile since T4's collector (and thus T5's base voltage) are close to 5V, this will turn on T4 and place a logic 1 (high) on the output.  This is the current condition for all inputs of a AND gate being high.

If *any* inputs to the input transistor T1 are low (logic 0), transistor T1 will be on.  The new inverter transistor T6 will then be off, and T2 will be on (instead of off in the NAND configuration).  The voltage across the 1KΩ resistor connected to T3's base will rise to a efficiently high level to turn on T3 and place a logic 0 (low) on the output.

The emitter voltage of T4 will be equal to T3 V\$_{CE}\$, about 0.2V.  The base potential will be T3 V\$_{BE}\$, plus T2 V\$_{CE}\$, or a total of about 0.9V.  Because of the Darlington configuration, this difference (0.7V) will not be enough to turn on T4.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the original source of this circuit in the [SN7400 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn7400):

[image: SN7400 circuit]

It's a NAND gate. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic#Implementation) explain it thus:

> When all the inputs are held at high voltage, the base-emitter junctions of the multiple-emitter transistor are reverse-biased. [A] small “collector” current (approximately 10µA) is drawn by each of the inputs. This is because the transistor is in reverse-active mode. An approximately constant current flows from the positive rail, through the resistor and into the base of the multiple emitter transistor. This current passes through the base-emitter junction of the output transistor [here: T2 and T3], allowing it to conduct and pulling the output voltage low (logical zero).

Answer (score 1):

CL is close but the schematic in the original post is actually a SN7410 which is a 3 input version that is identical to the 7400 in operation but with three inputs. [7410 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7410.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When all the emitters (inputs) are held high, a small current will flow in the base-collector diode to provide base current to the next transistor causing it to saturate. This will turn on the bottom transistor of the totem pole giving a low output. A low on any combination of inputs will cause the input transistor to saturate, steering current away from the next transistor. It will be in cutoff, and the 1k6 resistor will provide base current to the upper transistor causing a high output.  Yes, it's just that simple!